# how to call base_url in js file

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

i want to call `base_url()` in js file because i want to call ajax in jquery

its my php file

```
$.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo site_url('home/update');?>',
        data: {
        email:email 
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#feedback').text(data).css('color','green');
        },

        });       
         } 
        else
        {
            $('#feedback').text('insert a valid email').css('color','red');
        }

        });
```

but i want to call in js file but i am confused how can i fix this
because we can't call tags in js file

Comment: JS files do not get parsed for server-side code. If you want to provide data to a function, add it as a `data` attribute on the element which raises the event, then read it back in JS using `$(this).data('foo');`

Comment: i am new in CI please send the code with example..

Comment: Number of options, the best thing to do is to have your ajax call pull the action url. Then you can assign the site url to the form without worrying about the JS.

Answer (score 2):

there is one more solution define

```
<script>
 var base_url=<?php echo base_url();?>
</script>
```

in your PHP file and use this in your js file.

If the code is in JS script file you can always store this value in hidden input field and access that.
like:

```
<input type="hidden" id='base_url' value="<?php echo base_url();?>" >
```

And in JS file

```
var base_url = $('#base_url').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
    var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
</script>
```

- Write the above code in header.php file
- Then use 'base_url' variable in all js files you want..

  ```
  $.ajax({
  url: base_url+'home/update');?>',
  data: {
  email:email 
  },
  type: "POST",
  success: function(data) {
      $('#feedback').text(data).css('color','green');
  },

  });       
   } 
  else
  {
      $('#feedback').text('insert a valid email').css('color','red');
  }

  });
  ```

Answer (score 1):

JS files do not get parsed for server-side code. If you want to provide data to a function, add it as a data attribute on the element which raises the event, then read it back in JS using `$(this).data('foo');`, something like this:

```html
<button id="foo" data-action="<?php echo site_url('home/update');?>" data-email="<?php echo $email; ?>">Update</button>
```

```js
$('#foo').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).data('action'),
        data: { email: $(this).data('email') },
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#feedback').text(data).css('color','green');
        },
    });   
});
```

Comment: i did it thanx @stackoverflow.. :) and thax Rory McCrossan